# ddclient invalid login

Tags: dns, ddclient

I am trying make a dns registry using ddclient, here is my ddclient.conf

```
protocol=nsupdate
use=if, if=eth0
example.mydomain.com
```

and I got the error when I ran the ddclient :

ddclient[3507] WARNING: skiiping host example.mydomain.com: 'login=' is an invalid login.

I can see that eth0 has already valid IP.
I already installed bind9 and without any login, password or key I can make dns registry with nsupdate command from terminal. What I am doing wrong?

Thank you.